# Синтаксис sass/scss

Tags: scss, sass, синтаксис

как из этой строчки `scss`

```css
.checkbox._error .checkbox__label::before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem $color-red
}
```

сделать то же самое на `sass`?

Answer (score 1):

```
.checkbox._error .checkbox__label::before
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5rem $color-red
```